# Разные статус-коды с сервера и локально

Tags: сервер, http, requests

Запускаю один и тот же код с сервера и локально. Локально запрос выполняется успешно и получаю status_code=200, с сервера же возвращается status_code=402 (Payment Required). Сам скрипт просто перестал работать в связи с тем, что сервер стал отдавать код 402. Также запускал данный скрипт и с другого сервера - результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 402 вот что оней говорится

> The 402 (Payment Required) status code is reserved for future use.
>
> The original idea may have been that commercial websites and APIs
> would want to have a default way to communicate that a HTTP request
> can be repeated, after a user paid for service.

[402 Payment Required](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#402) — предполагается использовать в будущем. В настоящий момент не используется. Этот код предусмотрен для платных пользовательских сервисов, а не для хостинговых компаний. Имеется в виду, что эта ошибка не будет выдана хостинговым провайдером в случае просроченной оплаты его услуг. Зарезервирован, начиная с HTTP/1.1.

На ваш вопрос не возможно ответить без знаний о самом сервере на котором вы развернули приложение.